# How to do WSSE Authentication implementation in android java according to php part within webserver?

Tags: java, php, encryption, ws-security, wsse

I use symfony2 for web server and use wsse authentication with x-wsse header.

The question actually is about which exact functions I should use in Java to give the same result as in PHP.

PHP part for header generation:

```
$nonce = substr( md5( uniqid( 'nonce_', true ) ), 0, 16 );
$nonceHigh = base64_encode( $nonce );
$passwordDigest = base64_encode( sha1( $nonce . $created . $password . "{" . $user->getSalt() . "}", true ) );
$header = "UsernameToken Username=\"{$username}\", PasswordDigest=\"{$passwordDigest}\", Nonce=\"{$nonceHigh}\", Created=\"{$created}\"";
```

PHP part for header verify:

```
$expected = base64_encode( sha1( base64_decode( $nonce ) . $created . $secret, true ) );
```

I don't know why it uses *nonceHigh* instead of nonce directly? I believe this cause the problem in java. And I also don't know should generate nonce or use the one generate from server. In order to do the compare, I reused the nonce from server to generate digest.

```
byte [] nonceLow = Base64.decode(nonceHigh, Base64.DEFAULT); // nonceHigh is from above
String nonce = String.valueOf(nonceLow); // this give strange result. is it wrong?
String temp = nonce + format(now) + password;
try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    //new String(Base64.encodeBase64(md.digest(temp.getBytes())));
    digest = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(temp.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.DEFAULT);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AuthenticationException(e.getMessage(), e);
}

String wsse =
    "UsernameToken Username=\"" + username
        + "\", "
        + "PasswordDigest=\""
        + digest
        + "\", "
        + "Nonce=\""
        + nonceHIGH
        + "\", "
        + "Created=\""
        + format(now)
        + "\"";
```

Question is:

1. Why PHP uses *nonceHight* instead of *nonce*?
2. android java `Base64.encodeToString() == php base64_encode()`?
3. android java `Base64.decode() == php base64_decode()`?

Comment: Can you tell me how you generated the timestamp? what is the method format? I have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629847/wsse-timestamp-generation-in-android, can you help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Nobody answer. Ok, I put my found here in case somebody meet the same issue. This solve the problem.

```
Base64.encodeToString(temp.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Comment: Hi Yan, I'm facing the same problem here. But I don't understand how you corrected the problem. Can you post your entire code here please ?